# Install a Microsoft program with existing 64-bit installations

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Project Pro, which has a setup.exe for both 32 and 64-bit. It also has one master auto-run setup, which I'm assuming would let me choose the components and location to install and etc. However, when I run it, I immediately get an error saying that I can't go forth without uninstalling my existing 64-bit office programs. I have no intention of installing Project in 32-bit in the first place--it just rejects me before letting me choose. Is there any way to get around it? I can search the disk and launch a x64 installer, but that just goes ahead and installs everything without giving me the aforementioned component/location options.

Comment: I would contact Microsoft about this issue, or try the Microsoft technet forums....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?category=officeitpro

Comment: All versions of Office, and all programs within the suite itself, since 2010 in my personal experience have had separate setup.exe files for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  Based on the error your getting you have a 32-bit Project installer.  With physical disks, the default choice is 32-bit because of add-on compatibility reasons.  Run the 64-bit installer manually.

Comment: @Ramhound This program was offered on Dreamspark at my school, so I'm installing it off an iso as opposed to a disk. I can indeed manually run the 64-bit installer but, as mentioned, doing that does not allow me to choose where I want to install it and other options--it's just straight up a progress bar screen that starts installing.

Comment: So use a command prompt to configure it, works on all .msi files, which I presume is what the package is